# Serverside Google Mobile Vision for text decoding

Tags: java, text, server, ocr, android-vision

I'd like to use [Google Mobile Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/) (for Android) on a server, not on a mobile device. Is it possible, or only works within the Android SDK framework / environment? Is there a server-side port available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Cloud Vision API is server-side, and provides face detection and OCR:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/